# how to stop a python script before it goes to end

Tags: python

In the main script, I want to stop it under some condition. I tried `return` but it is wrong since it is outside the function. I tried `exit`, but it does not stop. See the following:

```
print 'step 1'
exit
print 'step 2'
```

what should I do ? 
the version I used is IDLE 2.7.5+

Comment: Actually you shouldn’t have code outside functions. The established convention is that the only code outside functions (except for declarations) should be a call to a `main` function: [What does `if __name__ == "__main__":` do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/419163)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `exit()`

```
from sys import exit
print 'step 1'
exit()
print 'step 2'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not in a function, use [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Note that this will exit python **entirely,** even if called from a module that's inside a larger program.

It will usually be better organization to `return` from a function, and keep as much code inside functions as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to exit a Python script is to simply raise the [`SystemExit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception with [`raise`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

```
print 'step 1'
raise SystemExit
print 'step 2'
```

This solution does exactly what [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) does, except that you do not need to import `sys` first.

---

Also, your specific problem was caused by the fact that you were not actually calling the `exit` function:

```
print 'step 1'
exit() # Add () after exit to call the function
print 'step 2'
```

However, you should not use this solution because it is considered a bad practice.  Instead, you should use `sys.exit` or `raise` as shown above.